# How can I get the body of the postrequest in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting my head around node.js and trying to construct a post request, this is my server.js file:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.post('/api/postrequest', function(req, res) {
        console.log('inside postrequest');
        console.log(req.body); //this is empty????
        });

    // application -------------------------------------------------------------
    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
    });
};
```

I would like to filter data from the request so try to verify what is in req.body. The problem is it is empty : {}. To test I am using Postman to submit the request:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/postrequest
```

Using the raw format to post this json:

```
{"name":"Eddie"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a middleware like [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) to do that. Do an `npm install body-parser` and require it in your app with

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

Then use it like so

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended': 'true'}));
```

Comment: I pasted those lines but still returns empty {}. With postman I use the raw json option with 'post'. Do I need to put in a header too?

Comment: Yes put in a `Content-Type` header as `application/json` if you're passing a JSON data. You can simply pass the data as form data too without any headers.